# stopping web audio oscillator without clicks

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

when executing this code i'm getting this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'linearRampToValueAtTime' on 'AudioParam': The provided double value is non-finite."

```
var ac = new window.AudioContext() || new window.webkit.AudioContext();
var osc;
var gain = ac.createGain();

function playosc() {
    osc = ac.createOscillator();
    osc.frequency.value = 440;
    osc.connect(gain);
    gain.connect(ac.destination);
    gain.gain.setValueAtTime(0, ac.currentTime);
    gain.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(0.3, ac.currentTime + 0.01);
    osc.start();
}

function stoposc() {
    gain.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(0, ac.endTime - 0.01);
    osc.stop(ac.endTime);
}
```

& when in place of ac.endTime is just endTime  - "endTime is not defined" error occures. maybe someone can explain why is it so? thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no [AudioContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext) `endTime` property. Doing `AudioContext.endTime` returns undefined, so you have `undefined-.01` that returns `NaN` which is not finite. You will want to use `currentTime` like you did when creating the oscillator

```
function stoposc() {
    gain.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(0, ac.currentTime + .01);
    osc.stop(ac.currentTime + .02);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this way it clicks then stopping. any other suggestions?